# Faced error during update Alamofire to version 4.0 for my old project

Tags: ios, cocoapods, alamofire, xcode8

I'm using the old version from Alamofire in one old project and now I want to update it to swift 3.0 and I want to update Alamofire also to version 4.0 but after add version number at pod file to pod alamofire and make pod install again I have this error at all time , I tried to make pod update but the process take a long time without any result like infinite process

[image]

**Updated:**

I tried this command through terminal " pod update " but this error appeared after waiting 15 mins.

[image]

I searched on this issue and it's from networks but I tried through 3 networks and the same result.
How I can solve this issue now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1. In your podfile update to: `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'`
2. In your podfile update to: `platform :ios, '9.0'` (or higher)
3. Change your deployment target in Xcode to iOS 9.0 or higher
4. Do a `pod update`

Comment: I make everything here but now I realized all my problem from my network it prevents me to make pod update correctly , I will solve this problem then I will try again , Thanks.

Comment: @SamahAhmed, np glad to help.

Comment: I updated my post again please can you see the last picture.